# Create vertical lines for an interval using highstocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, highcharts

I would like to know if it is possible somehow to create vertical lines (plotLines) in the xAxis for a defined interval.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/kZkWZ/) of one of those plot lines for a given date. Would it be possible to define it for a given interval?

```
    xAxis: {
          tickInterval: 5 * 4 * 1000,
        lineColor: '#FF0000',
        lineWidth: 1,
        plotLines: [{
            value: Date.UTC(2014,03,05),
            width: 1,
            color: 'green',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
        }]
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in Highcharts there's not such thing like range for plotLines. However you cna create simple function for that: http://jsfiddle.net/kZkWZ/57/

```
function generatePlotLines(from, to, interval) {
    var plotLines = [];

    while (from < to) {
        from += interval;
        plotLines.push({
            value: from,
            width: 1,
            color: 'green',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
            label: {
                text: 'some name',
                align: 'right',
                y: 122,
                x: 0
            }
        })
    }

    return plotLines;
}


$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

    xAxis: {
        plotLines: generatePlotLines(Date.UTC(2011, 0, 1), Date.UTC(2011, 3, 1), 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a [`plotBand`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands). This allows a range to be used. General usage is like:

```
        xAxis: {        
            plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
                color: '#FCFFC5',
                from: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2),
                to: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4)
            }],
...
```

EDIT - Based on clarification you can generate a series like so:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {
            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[1];
            var Xmin = this.xAxis[0].min;
            var Xmax = this.xAxis[0].max;
            //console.log(Xmin);
            //console.log(Xmax);
            series.pointInterval = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
            series.pointStart = Date.UTC(2011, 0, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            for (var i = Xmin; i < Xmax; i = i + (24 * 3600 * 1000)) {
                var x = i,
                    y = 1;
                series.addPoint([x, y], true);
            }

        }
    }
},
```

You need to make that new series prior (but with no data):

```
series: [{
    name: 'USD to EUR',
    data: usdeur
}, {
    name: 'Interval',
    type: 'column',
    data: []
}
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kZkWZ/56/). Doing this every second on that chart you are using is going to grind. Mine is doing it every day. Doing it every minute takes a long time. Note that I am only adding it to the viewable min/max on load. If you want it to span the entire chart you are going to have to define your own `Xmin` and `Xmax`.

Comment: But that's not an interval, that's a range. I want to add a line every X seconds without having to define the range.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought you meant a span interval. Why not create a new series with a column that goes the entire height of the chart?

Comment: It doesn't look like the proper way to do it but more like a hack. It doesn't fill the rest of the graph, its quite thick...

Comment: The thickness is just the default width of the column. To expand the total chart you need to give the start/end times. Do you really need a plot line every second? You could put a gridLine every second?

Comment: Not every second, it will be every 8 hours. And the graphic is static, i won't probably need to use the `load` for it. A gridLine?

Comment: Yes, the grid lines from the xAxi/yAxis out into the chart area. Check out `tickInterval` and `gridLineWidth` (defaults to 0 on xAxis so you need to give it a value) in the API. Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/e63cP/. So on your xAxis every 8 minuutes would be `tickInterval: 8 * 60 * 1000`. This would be much faster than creating a series or a plotLine.

Comment: I'm trying to add the `xAxis` array as you have it in your jsfiddle but it doesn't work on highstocks.

Comment: But now I'm having troubles when scaling the graph to an smaller area which is smaller than the xAxis interval, then weird things start to happen with the value lines of the graph.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. It also made the `1 day` filter in the `zoom` section to stop working properly. Finally I adopted another proposed solution. Thanks anyway!